# Get Facebook group members count in Node.js

Tags: node.js, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to do that? I am playing with their explorer and I can't get the information of members..I just need to count members.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fgroups%2Ffree.code.camp.you.can.do.this%2F&version=v2.5

All groups are open/public. Is there any npm module that can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to get the Group ID with the Search API: `/search?type=group&q=free.code.camp.you.can.do.this`

The Group ID is "1013157175381620", so that´s what you can use to access the members:

```
/1013157175381620/members
```

Now you have to use that API endpoit to get all members and count them. Most likely you will need to use Paging to get all of them: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging

Or even better: `/1013157175381620/members?summary=true&limit=1`

Result:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "...",
      "administrator": false,
      "id": "..."
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "next": "..."
  },
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 529
  }
}
```

Comment: hm...It does not seem to be working for me...What goes before this code `/1013157175381620/members?summary=true&limit=1
` ?
tnx for answer!

Comment: make sure you learn about access tokens too: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: for example: https://graph.facebook.com/1013157175381620/members?access_token=[app-access-token] - an app token should be good enough for a public group.

Comment: ok, tnx!. But I have a little problem -- this does not work on FB explorer, but it works if i put link in url with token...However that will be enough. tnx!

Comment: in the api explorer, you don´t need to add the token...make sure you undertstand how the explorer works, it´s one of the most important tools for facebook development.

Comment: i did not add token in graph api. Just deleted it. Everything else is same

Comment: then you most likely did not use a token. again, make sure to know how the explorer works. we can´t help you if you just say "it does not work" ;)

Comment: I figured out.. I was putting `https://graph.facebook.com` in explorer and instead it should be blank. Now it works...

Comment: Ok, I used the API in Node.js but Facebook blocked me. I was getting members count number of 950 groups. I have an array with facebook links of each 950 city. Then I did forEach loop and inserted the working code you explained to me. Is there a way to bypass this limit?


`{ message: 'It looks like you were misusing this feature by going too fast. You’ve been blocked from using it.\n\nLearn more about blocks in the Help Center.',
  type: 'OAuthException',
  code: 368,
  error_subcode: 1390008,
  fbtrace_id: 'Horz1Z+YCrj' }`

Comment: no, you cannot bypass limits, you need to do less calls. why not just use the second option of my answer? that would only be one api call to get the member count.

Comment: remember, if you hit the limits, you are most likely doing something that you are not supposed to do.

Comment: I am using your second option but I have array of 950 groups that i am fetching every 60 seconds, because of limit. However after 1 hour it says that my token has expired. I dont know how to make script that can request new token on the fly...

Comment: just as i said: you are doing something you are not supposed to do ;) - getting the current members count of 950 groups every minute is WAY too much, why not do that once per day and per group and spread it through the day? for example, get the members count of 100 groups each hour.

Comment: btw, do not try to circument api limits. they are there for a reason and i guess you don´t want to get banned ;)

Comment: I am not getting 950 groups member count every minute, I am getting just one every minute, then next one after two minutes and so on.Here is code
https://github.com/samosale/fccCities/blob/master/index.js

Comment: hard to read that code without indentation, but that is some REEEALLY bad coding. you basically start hundreds of timeouts. why not just use setInterval once? either way, if you want to stick to that code, debug it and try to find out why there are so many api calls in a short time. one api call in one minute is definitely no problem, but i guess your code is doing a lot more.

Comment: you know, there is a very important design pattern: "do not create functions in a loop" - that´s what you are doing right now.